# Generate a Continuous Square Wave with a specified Duty Cycle and Time Resolution, without using the square built-in function

Tags: matlab

The problem is that I get nothing plotted.

Here is my code:

```
T0=2;                          % signal's period, in seconds
dur=20;                        % total signal duration, in seconds
res=0.02;                      % time's resolution, in seconds
t=0:res:dur-res;               % time vector, which has exactly 1000 elements
duty=1/4;                      % duty cycle
x(dur/res)=0;                  % must have equal number of elements as t, plot won't work otherwise
for t=0:res:dur-res            % period is 2s, so for t between 0 and 0.5 , 2 and 2.5, 4 and 4.5, etc (the 'desired interval'), all x values will be 1, and the rest will be 0 
    mlt=1;
    if t<=mlt*T0*duty          % calculating if t is in desired interval
        x(round(1+(t/res)))=1; % using round because I have some error despite the number (t/res) being always integer, I add 1 so the index is not 0
    else x(round(1+(t/res)))=0;
    end
    if mod(t,2)==0             % if t enters the desired interval
        mlt=mlt+4;             % going to the next period's desired interval. just trying to make it work for a period of 2 seconds now, will figure out a formula later
    end
end
s=sin(x*pi/2);                 % if x=0, the sine is 0, if x=1, the sine is 1. using sine because I need it to be a continuous function

plot(t,s);
axis ([0 20 0 1]);
```

I hope the comments are comprehensive.
I am a very inexperienced MATLAB user, I've been only using it for a week.
Also, if you are aware of an easier way to solve my exercise (yes, this is homework), I would gladly analyze it.

Comment: An apparent problem in your code is that you're initializing `t` in the 4th line, but then you're also  using `t` as a loop variable. So, `t` does not remain a vector anymore that you previously initialized. Rather, it becomes a 1x1 variable which changes its value on every iteration. Fix is that: either change the name of your loop variable, or move this line `t=0:res:dur-res;` after your loop ends (and before using `plot` command)

Comment: Many thanks! I was not aware of that, as MATLAB told me that the t variable was still 1x1000 ,but it turns out to be how you said. Also, a big mistake was to initialize mlt inside the foor loop, so I would never get past the first period.